# jquery code doesn't support in internet explorer 8 or nine

Tags: jquery

```
$("#browser-by-category, #browser-by-author").accordion({header: "h3",
                                        animated: "slide",
                                        event: "click",
                                        collapsible: true,
                                        active: false,
                                        heightStyle: "content"
                                    });
```

Error: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion'

Comment: Have you try with a previous version of jQuery ?

Comment: Are you sure you have included jQuery UI, together with accordion, inside your page?

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis make it an answer, he missed the JQuery UI lib (JS+CSS then)

Answer (score 1):

Making this an answer, as suggested by @TecHunter above:

The OP seems to have missed adding either the jQuery UI library itself, or the accordion plugin of the jQuery UI library